# Debian/Linux weird mdraid state

Tags: linux, debian, raid, software-raid

Why is md1 state UU, md0 is U_ and md2 is _U?

nvme1n1 is broken here.

Can I safely replace nvme1n1 now?

You can see md2 state, nvme0n1p3 seems removed but nvme1n1p3 seems active.
How can I safely replace the broken disk nvme1n1 here? What happend here?

Can I just clone /dev/nvme1n1p3 to /dev/nvme0n1p3?
Or how can I simply resync raid in md2 array? /dev/nvme0n1p3 has a 2 month old state and current OS state is on /dev/nvme1n1p3

Edit:
For now im gonna copy the partition:

dd if=/dev/nvme1n1p3 of=/dev/nvme0n1p3

Should i rebuild the raid afterwise or can i just replace the faulty disk?

cat /prod/mdstat output

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme1n1p2[1]
      523264 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[0]
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md2 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1]
      465894720 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

MD states:

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Mar 15 21:50:14 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Thu Jun 17 14:43:33 2021
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:0
              UUID : 41a6fa02:cafe993c:ba95e089:69e1cee9
            Events : 3691713

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        1        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p1
       -       0        0        1      removed
```

```
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Mar 15 21:50:15 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 523264 (511.00 MiB 535.82 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 523264 (511.00 MiB 535.82 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Thu Jun 17 06:26:55 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:1
              UUID : 28bb218f:54e5dcee:56f85d57:5c4577ba
            Events : 131

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        2        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p2
       1     259        6        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

```
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Mar 15 21:50:15 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 465894720 (444.31 GiB 477.08 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 465894720 (444.31 GiB 477.08 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Jun 17 14:52:09 2021
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : rescue:2
              UUID : 3340d601:90ff36ca:da246d8d:c26b994f
            Events : 46166134

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1     259        7        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p
```

/dev/nvme1n1 is broken:

```
=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
- NVM subsystem reliability has been degraded

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x04
Temperature:                        59 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    149%
```

Comment: In general, it is *not safe* to clone md component device. I'd rather create *new* (degraded) array and clone the *contents* of the old array, to be sure I don't clone superblocks. // Please add `mdadm --examine /dev/nvme[01]n1p3` (which shows decoded md superblocks from those devices); `blkid` and `lsblk` outputs wouldn't hurt too.